# Python interactive terminal results are inconsistent with script results

Tags: python

interactive terminal results:

```
In [11]: a=1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

In [12]: b=1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

In [13]: a is b
Out[13]: False
```

script results:

```
# overflow in ~ [13:55:16]
» python -c "a=1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111;b=1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111; print a is b"

True
```

Emmmmm. I think the result should be False... Because `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` is much larger than `256`

I know `is` is not an equality test. But, when Python declares a variable(immutable type), like `b = 1`, it will find out whether the object has been declared in the old object(`a = 1`). If the object is declared(`a = 1`), the variable will point directly to the old object and will not apply for new memory space.(`a is b` is `True`)

```
In [2]: a=1

In [3]: b=1

In [4]: a is b
Out[4]: True
```

emmmm. right?

As for [“is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers). It explains the usage of `is`, but I still don't understand why these two methods lead to different results. :(

Maybe, it just depends on the Python implementation and runtime environment.

Comment: `is` is not an equality test.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you are looking for. Use `is` is for identity testing and `==` for equality testing. Do not rely on `is` to check for equality.

Equality refers to the value of the object while identity refers to the pointer to the same object id. For example, if you run this in your terminal, `is` will return `False`:

```
a = 1111
b = int('1111')

print(a == b)
>>True
print(a is b)
>>False
```

The assumption to use `is` not for identity test is not recommended and its behaviour depends on the Python implementation and runtime environment. I somehow also suspect because of how Python read your integers where they are repeated. For a further example:

```
a = 257
b = 257
a is b
>>False
```

From the docs:

> Return value: New reference. Create a new integer object with a value
>   of ival.
>
> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all
>   integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you
>   actually just get back a reference to the existing object. So it
>   should be possible to change the value of 1. I suspect the behaviour
>   of Python in this case is undefined. :-)

For optimization, short integers actually just refer back to the same object, this should also apply if you changed a single number in your value (non-repeated) above `256`, it will return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting.

```
Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:21:55) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.1.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: a=1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111                                                                
In [2]: b=1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

In [3]: id(a),id(b)                                                                                                           
Out[3]: (139945897647488, 139945897647536)

In [4]: len(str(a))                                                                                                           
Out[4]: 52
```

Comment: I tried to explain the usage of `is` to my friends, but something went wrong in this case. XD

Comment: also note if you make them strings instead of ints `in` outputs `True`

Comment: "is" means same object,  I rarely use it.